# How to add 2 data sets in SSRS

Tags: dataset, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have 2 data sets that have the common column VNO. Now I want to get the report in ssrs like

VDate, Count('*') from B for Vdate, Count('*') from A for Vdate

Can anyone help me with the way, I tried the lookup but not able to get this output.

[image]

Note: I cannot join these two tables in SQL as these 2 tables are on separate instances and they are not connected and don't have permission to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use LOOKUPSET() . This returns an array which you can then check the length of like this

```
=LookupSet(Fields!InvoiceDate.Value, Fields!VDate.Value, Fields!VNO.Value, "DataSetB").Length
```

The 3rd argument is the returned value but as you are only getting a count, it does not matter what we return there. `DataSetB` is the case sensitive name of your second dataset.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. This solution doesn't work for me but yes, I get the hint out of it. If we are using the Length function on the varchar field then it will count the character, not the count which I was expecting. So I have used 

split(Join(LookupSet(Fields!VDate.Value, Fields!EnteredDate.Value, Fields!VNO.Value, "DS_NAP"), ","),",").Length

which is perfect for me. Thank you @Alan